# Оптимизация запроса sql / кода java

Tags: java, sql, база-данных

Доброго времени суток.

Есть проблема, которую не могу решить уже второй день. Написал приложение, которое парсирует из `XML файла` данные и записывает их в `БД`. Все как бы работает, но время записи одного `файла XML` (размером 15 килобайт) занимает около 3 минут. А файлы будут и по 10 мегабайт и по 20. 
Всего в коде у меня 3 метода, в которых я записываю данные в БД. Вот пример одного метода:

```
public void insertToPhoto(String id_photo, int id_phototype , int maxzoomlevel, int width, int height, int angle, String id_stage) throws SQLException {

          Connection conn = null;
          PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            try {
              conn = getConnection();
              String query = "insert into photos(id_photo, id_phototype, maxzoomlevel, width, height, angle, id_stage) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
              pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
              pstmt.setString(1, id_photo); // set input parameter 
              pstmt.setInt(2, id_phototype); // set input parameter 
              pstmt.setInt(3, maxzoomlevel); // set input parameter 
              pstmt.setInt(4, width); // set input parameter 
              pstmt.setInt(5, height); // set input parameter 
              pstmt.setInt(6, angle); // set input parameter 
              pstmt.setString(7, id_stage); // set input parameter 

              pstmt.executeUpdate();
              conn.commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if(conn != null){
                    try{
                        conn.rollback();
                    }
                    catch(SQLException ex){


                    }
                }

            } finally {

                conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            }                
      }
```

И таких их 3. Данные их `XML файла` я записываю в `List<>`. После всего этого я при помощи `for(obj x: list)` вытягиваю данные и записываю их в `БД`.  Вот кусочек кода:

```
for(Datenstrom x: datList){
                for(WGS y: x.getWgs()){     
                    for(Bilder bil: x.getBilder()){
                        idUUIDStage = mq.getUUID();
                        con.insertToStage(idUUIDStage, bil.getNr(), todayq, todayq, Integer.parseInt(con.getIDSection(Integer.toString(x.asb.getVnk()), Integer.toString(x.asb.getNnk()))), y.getStation(), 0.0, 0.0, 0, x.zuordnung.getFS());  

                    }
                }

                for(Bilder bilder: x.getBilder()) {

                    idUUIDPhoto = mq.getUUID();

                    Image im = new Image(bilder.getD());

                    con.insertToPhoto(idUUIDPhoto, bilder.getNr(), im.getCountZoom(), Image.widthImage(), Image.heightImage(), 50, con.getIDStage(bilder.getStation()));


            }
```

Как мне оптимизировать все это, что бы процесс записи в `БД` проходил быстрее ? Где я сделал не правильно и что можно было бы изменить ?

Comment: Это ведь понятно getConnection - нужно использовать пул конекшенов, иначе каждый раз новое соединение создаётся (как реализован этот метод?).

Если загружаете много данных (пкетом) то наверное логично делать это в одной транзакции, так будет быстрее.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема и есть в этом. Я только учусь ) 
А как мне сделать, что бы было только одно соединение на 3 запроса ? 
Никогда еще не делал транзакции (

Comment: Цикл внутри conn = getConnection(); ... conn.commit(); делать

Comment: А есть какой нибудь пример по которому можно хорошо понять транзакции ? 
Я сейчас попробую сделать ее, если все получится, то думаю ваш комментарий можно будет разместить как ответ.

Comment: если парсируемых xml по 10мег и более достаточно много (преобладающее большинство) то сам процесс занесение в базу можно ускорить с помощью LOAD DATA INFILE (если база mysql (конкретного упоминания об этом не нашёл)), сформировав файл парсированием xml.

Comment: @Вадим спасибо, почитаю об этом.
сделал синглетон коннектор. что бы одно соединение было а не создавалась куча целая с каждым инсертом. но не на много это помогло )

Я слышал, что Postgres без транзакции вообще еле еле заносит данные в БД. Попробую сделать транзакцию еще, но я до этого дня не делал ни разу ее (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну примерно так:

```
conn = getConnection();    
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
    ...
    stmt1.execute();
    ...
    stmt2.execute();
    conn.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    conn.rollback();
}
```

Неплохо было бы ещё стейтменты закрыть.

Comment: Вот нашел [пример](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/) 

У меня было 3 метода в которые я как параметры передавал данные для записи из XML файла. Теперь я понял, что надо создать 1 метод и в нем будет 3 insert'a (поправьте меня если не прав). Если я понял Вас правильно, то как мне передать все данные в этот один метод. Или может быть 3 транзакции для 3 методов ?

Comment: Если попадание данных в базу частями критично, то конечно нужна одна транзакция + меньше транзакций будет быстрее работать.

Comment: А как быть тогда с параметрами (данными из файла которые я вытягиваю из List и вставляю как параметр в методе) при записи ?

Answer (score 2):

Главная идея — это убрать `conn.commit();`

Для этого желательно взять одно подключение к базе, поставить у него `setAutoCommit(false);`, навставлять строк в базу.

При этом учтите, что если вы сделаете *rollback*, то откатятся все вставки: тут надо понять, что плохого в том, что какая-то запись не вставилась.

Ну и в конце только `commit();`

А еще меня смущают два цикла по *getBilder*,

Имхо, с этим можно что-то сделать, и `con.getIDStage`, я думаю, тоже можно убрать.

Comment: я сейчас делаю синглетон класс для подключения к БД. а дальше буду делать по вашим советам ! Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего писать в базу не построчно, а балково. Как это делается на plain JDBC - честно, не помню.

Как вариант, использовать спринговые `JdbcTemplate` и его API (пример: класс `SimpleJdbcInsert#executeBatch`). Ну и тогда без проблем можно коммитить, например, каждые N-записей

Comment: Спасибо за совет. На данные момент сделал синглетон коннектор, сейчас попробую сделать транзакцию (просто не делал ее до сегодняшнего дня). Слышал, что Postgres еле еле заносит данные без транзакции. Если не выйдет, то попробую сделать по Вашему совету.

Comment: Транзакция добавит накладных расходов, это точно не ускорит код. Принципиально тут 2 проблемы - коммит (как вам уже указали) и итеративный инсерт (на это вам указал я). Причем, если вы поправите вторую проблему (например, сделаете стриминговую обработку xml и будете инсертить данные в БД, например, по 100 строк), то коммит перестанет быть проблемой.